# Does a node validates a transaction that comes with a block if it's already in its mempool?

Tags: block, nodes, mempool, validation

Except for checking for double spends, if there's a transaction in a block that's already in the node's mempool, it can theoretically skip its validation. Does it actually happen, or the nodes validate each transaction twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most expensive part of checking a transaction, ECDSA validation, is cached.

Comment: Didn't cache also the transaction itself?

Comment: Transaction validity can change (OP_CLTV).

Comment: Now I'm thinking about it, it can change even before that because there could've been a double spend attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Zero confirmed transaction are unsafe. Simillarly, it is not safe to validate using them as benchmark. See this example:

- You have a transaction *T1* that spends txouts of transaction *T* in mempool
- Another transaction *T2* in mempool spends outputs of *T1*
- In Block B

  - We have tranaction *T1'* that is double spend of *T1* with different output. This is possible since miner can directly include *T1'* in the block and it is valid.
  - We also have *T2* in B but it is invalid. Now validating *T2* based on mempool would be wrong. We have to consider all previous outputs and outputs in the current block.

Also note that bitcoind has to validate blocks which on different forks/chains. Mempool only has unconfirmed transaction on the longest chain

Comment: Nonsense, you can cache the validation, just not the UTXO check.